# Zurb Foundation Dropdown Button menu drops way too much

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I want to add a Dropdown Button from Foundation (like these: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown-buttons.html) to my site, using the "data-dropdown" property to link it to a list, as described in the doc-page at the bottom.
The dropdown works - however, somehow the list drops waaaay too much down when I click on the button (like 300px below the button).

I even tried to isolate the button on a blank page or without all my custom settings and styles, no luck. I have the latest Foundation 4.0.5 installed as a gem.
Does anyone have the same problem with this version of Foundation? Or is there a syntax-error in the doc-example? 
I copy+pasted exactly this code-snippet:

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1" class="button dropdown">Dropdown Button</a><br>

<ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown">
  <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for the help!

- Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this same issue a few days back. It seems to me that the new dropdown classes in Foundation 4 do not play nicely inside of div.columns elements. Consider the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 columns">
    <ul class="inline-list">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="button dropdown" data-dropdown="drop1">No Good</a>
        <ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="button dropdown" data-dropdown="drop2">Much Better</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<ul id="drop2" class="f-dropdown">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

In this example, 'drop1' is defined inside the 'large-6 columns' div, and when the corresponding button is clicked, it will display far below the button, just as you describe. In contrast, 'drop2' is defined outside of the div.columns, and it will display correctly.

From my experimentation, the dropdown can be defined inside of a row without issue. It's the columns that seem to cause the issue.

Comment: That works great, thank's a lot! I should have considered that myself since I was wondering why in the Foundation docs they had the list below the columns, too. Hope they fix it or at least put a hint inside the docs to not confuse newcomers.